# MsBuild cannot find Reference.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a project I want to build via MsBBuild, on a build server. But the build fails because of this error:

```
CSC: Source file 'Service References\MyService\Reference.cs' could not be found
```

I've opened the folder in windows explorer, and the file is there. What could possible be the error?

Its a 2001 error according to the log file.

Thanks.

Comment: Plese show us how is it added/used in proj file .

Comment: How it's used? It is a service reference which is added the normal way in the Service Reference Folder in my project.

Comment: I understand that , it would be better for everyone to analyze the content of the file also so that we can see how its used and determine what could be possibly wrong.

Comment: We'll need to see the proj file lines including Reference.cs to try to help you. Also, does VS clean-rebuilds your project OK? What happens if you run rebuild from CMD locally?

Comment: I just removed my service, add it again and it worked..